# NullPointerException when re-running a test

Tags: java, unit-testing, playframework, playframework-1.x

I am unit testing a Play Framework based application. As I read in the documentation, for the sake of clearing the state, before every test I reload the list of fixtures like this:

```
    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        Fixtures.deleteAll();
        Fixtures.load("data.yml");
        Logger.info("FIXTURES RELOADED");
    }
```

Then I go to the Web.based testing platform `(http://localhost:9000/@tests)`, choose a test that deals with fetching some data `(User u = User.findById(1l);)` and then assert against the data. It works.

However, if I try to select the test again, and rerun it, it fails with:

```
A java.lang.NullPointerException has been caught, Try to read name on null object models.User
```

If I stop the application completely and restart it, it runs again (the first time), but starting and stopping takes a bit of time and is quite tedious, if you do it 10 times a minute.

I am using Play 1.2.5

Comment: Is setup() called during every run?

Comment: Where do you insert your user object to DB?

Comment: try `@BeforeMethod` - instead of `@Before`.

Comment: @baraky in the Fixtures.load...

Comment: @Sudhanshu, yes, that's why I put a logging statement at the end

Comment: @R.J there is no BeforeMethod provided in the JUnit that comes with Play 1.2.5

Comment: `@BeforeClass` should exist though. I _think_ Play uses JUnit 4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is auto-incrementing user ID (on every insert) while trying to get user with ID 1 on every test.

You can get the newly created user ID and use it in your test or find user by other field that you definitely know.

Comment: That was exactly the problem. So, in my tests, I will avoid getting a user with findById, but rather with something I am sure will not change, like User.find("byUsername", "testuser1")